# Change settings of RadDesktopAlert telerik winform control after show

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, telerik

I try to change the AutoClose close property after the Telerik RadDesktopAlert is shown but it seems to don't work.

The only way I found is to hide and show the DesktopAlert again.

So :

```
RadDesktopAlert alert = new RadDesktopAlert();
alert.Show();
alert.AutoClose = true;
```

Won't work because it seems after popup show up property update will not be consider.

So the only way I found is :

```
RadDesktopAlert alert = new RadDesktopAlert();
alert.Show();
alert.AutoClose = true;
alert.Hide();
alert.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to change the default value of 10 seconds for the [RadDesktopAlert.AutoCloseDelay Property](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/p_telerik_wincontrols_ui_raddesktopalert_autoclosedelay.html).

Comment: no because I wanted to reactivate autoclose at the moment the user move the mouse and let the control close the popup automatically. But because the popup is already open it don't work. So for the moment I put the Hide method in a timer when user move mouse but it's not best way to do it I think.